# TabBar text not getting updated inside NestedScrollView on setState

Tags: flutter, dart

In my real project, I'm using `TabBar` inside `SliverPersistentHeader` which is wrapped with `NestedScrollView`. The problem is when I call `setState(() {})` the text doesn't update. Tough the actual value is updated. The text gets updated only when I perform scroll.

I know `Tab` is a `const` constructor and it is not supposed to be rebuilt on `setState(() {})`, however, when I run the same example without `NestedScrollView` and `SliverPersistentHeader` and the `TabBar` in `AppBar` it works as expected.

I've written a demo project showcasing the problem.

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _counter = 0;
  TabController _tabController;

  ScrollController _scrollController;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 1, vsync: this);
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          print('$_counter');
          return [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: SliverPersistentHeaderDelegateImpl(
                tabBar: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Tab $_counter',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[350],
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
                        blurRadius: 0),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverPersistentHeaderDelegateImpl
    extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final TabBar tabBar;
  final Decoration decoration;

  const SliverPersistentHeaderDelegateImpl({
    this.decoration,
    @required this.tabBar,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      child: tabBar,
      decoration: decoration,
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved it by using Providers

Comment: can you elaborate? Did you use a controller?

Comment: Hello, from what I remember is that you need to wrap `Tab` with Consumer.
For example,
TabBar(
    controller: _tabController,
    labelColor: Colors.black,
    tabs: [
    Consumer<YourModel>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => Tab(
      text: 'Tab $value',
    ))
  ],
),